# python-polars split string column into many columns by delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

In pandas, the following code will split the string from col1 into many columns. is there a way to do this in polars?

```
d = {'col1': ["a/b/c/d", "a/b/c/d"]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df[["a","b","c","d"]]=df["col1"].str.split('/',expand=True)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an algorithm that will automatically adjust for the required number of columns -- and should be quite performant.

Let's start with this data.  Notice that I've purposely added the empty string `""` and a null value - to show how the algorithm handles these values.  Also, the number of split strings varies widely.

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "my_str": ["cat", "cat/dog", None, "", "cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog"],
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (5, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────┐
│ my_str                      │
│ ---                         │
│ str                         │
╞═════════════════════════════╡
│ cat                         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ cat/dog                     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null                        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│                             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog │
└─────────────────────────────┘
```

##### The Algorithm

The algorithm below may be a bit more than you need, but you can edit/delete/add as you need.

```py
(
    df
    .with_row_count('id')
    .with_column(pl.col("my_str").str.split("/").alias("split_str"))
    .explode("split_str")
    .with_column(
        ("string_" + pl.arange(0, pl.count()).cast(pl.Utf8).str.zfill(2))
        .over("id")
        .alias("col_nm")
    )
    .pivot(
        index=['id', 'my_str'],
        values='split_str',
        columns='col_nm',
    )
    .with_column(
        pl.col('^string_.*$').fill_null("")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (5, 7)
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ id  ┆ my_str                      ┆ string_00 ┆ string_01 ┆ string_02 ┆ string_03 ┆ string_04 │
│ --- ┆ ---                         ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ u32 ┆ str                         ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       │
╞═════╪═════════════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ cat                         ┆ cat       ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ cat/dog                     ┆ cat       ┆ dog       ┆           ┆           ┆           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ null                        ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆                             ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ cat       ┆ dog       ┆ aardvark  ┆ mouse     ┆ frog      │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

##### How it works

We first assign a row number `id` (which we'll need later), and use [`split`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.string.ExprStringNameSpace.split.html#polars.internals.expr.string.ExprStringNameSpace.split) to separate the strings.  Note that the split strings form a list.

```py
(
    df
    .with_row_count('id')
    .with_column(pl.col("my_str").str.split("/").alias("split_str"))
)
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ my_str                      ┆ split_str                  │
│ --- ┆ ---                         ┆ ---                        │
│ u32 ┆ str                         ┆ list[str]                  │
╞═════╪═════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════╡
│ 0   ┆ cat                         ┆ ["cat"]                    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ cat/dog                     ┆ ["cat", "dog"]             │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ null                        ┆ null                       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆                             ┆ [""]                       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ ["cat", "dog", ... "frog"] │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘
```

Next, we'll use [`explode`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html) to put each string on its own row.  (Notice how the `id` column tracks the original row that each string came from.)

```py
(
    df
    .with_row_count('id')
    .with_column(pl.col("my_str").str.split("/").alias("split_str"))
    .explode("split_str")
)
```

```
shape: (10, 3)
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ id  ┆ my_str                      ┆ split_str │
│ --- ┆ ---                         ┆ ---       │
│ u32 ┆ str                         ┆ str       │
╞═════╪═════════════════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ cat                         ┆ cat       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ cat/dog                     ┆ cat       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ cat/dog                     ┆ dog       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ null                        ┆ null      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆                             ┆           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ cat       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ dog       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ aardvark  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ mouse     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ frog      │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

In the next step, we're going to generate our column names.  I chose to call each column `string_XX` where `XX` is the offset with regards to the original string.

I've used the handy [`zfill`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.string.ExprStringNameSpace.zfill.html) expression so that `1` becomes `01`.  (This makes sure that `string_02` comes before `string_10` if you decide to sort your columns later.)

You can substitute your own naming in this step as you need.

```py
(
    df
    .with_row_count('id')
    .with_column(pl.col("my_str").str.split("/").alias("split_str"))
    .explode("split_str")
    .with_column(
        ("string_" + pl.arange(0, pl.count()).cast(pl.Utf8).str.zfill(2))
        .over("id")
        .alias("col_nm")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (10, 4)
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ id  ┆ my_str                      ┆ split_str ┆ col_nm    │
│ --- ┆ ---                         ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ u32 ┆ str                         ┆ str       ┆ str       │
╞═════╪═════════════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ cat                         ┆ cat       ┆ string_00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ cat/dog                     ┆ cat       ┆ string_00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ cat/dog                     ┆ dog       ┆ string_01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ null                        ┆ null      ┆ string_00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆                             ┆           ┆ string_00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ cat       ┆ string_00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ dog       ┆ string_01 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ aardvark  ┆ string_02 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ mouse     ┆ string_03 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ frog      ┆ string_04 │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

In the next step, we'll use the [`pivot`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html) function to place each string in its own column.

```py
(
    df
    .with_row_count('id')
    .with_column(pl.col("my_str").str.split("/").alias("split_str"))
    .explode("split_str")
    .with_column(
        ("string_" + pl.arange(0, pl.count()).cast(pl.Utf8).str.zfill(2))
        .over("id")
        .alias("col_nm")
    )
    .pivot(
        index=['id', 'my_str'],
        values='split_str',
        columns='col_nm',
    )
)
```

```
shape: (5, 7)
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ id  ┆ my_str                      ┆ string_00 ┆ string_01 ┆ string_02 ┆ string_03 ┆ string_04 │
│ --- ┆ ---                         ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ u32 ┆ str                         ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       │
╞═════╪═════════════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ cat                         ┆ cat       ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ cat/dog                     ┆ cat       ┆ dog       ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ null                        ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆                             ┆           ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog ┆ cat       ┆ dog       ┆ aardvark  ┆ mouse     ┆ frog      │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

All that remains is to use [`fill_null`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.fill_null.html) to replace the `null` values with an empty string `""`.  Notice that I've used a regex expression in the [`col`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.col.html) expression to target only those columns whose names start with "string_".  (Depending on your other data, you may not want to replace null with `""` everywhere in your data.)

Comment: thanks so much works very well for my requirements

Comment: @cbilot this is great however is there a way not to get rid of extra columns that are present in a dataframe. I could add all extra columns needed as an index to the pivot but  have a few so might be  inefficient. any suggestions?

Comment: You can always use `join` or `hstack` to add the new columns to your existing DataFrame.  Indeed, for many algorithms (especially those involving sorts, explodes, etc.) to do them off to the side, and then add the results back to your DataFrame.

Answer (score 9):

You can use struct datatype, as described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74219166:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
       "my_str": ["cat", "cat/dog", None, "", "cat/dog/aardvark/mouse/frog"],
})
df.select(pl.col('my_str').str.split('/')
    .arr.to_struct(n_field_strategy="max_width")).unnest('my_str')
```

Notice you must use `n_field_strategy="max_width"`, otherwise, `unnest()` will create only 1 column.

Comment: It is clearly more elegant than using a pivot

Comment: The answer should now use `.list` instead of `.arr` with recent versions of polars.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply()` method

```
import polars as pl
from polars import col

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'col1': ["a/b/c/d", "e/f/j/k"]
})

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────┐
│ col1    │
│ ---     │
│ str     │
╞═════════╡
│ a/b/c/d │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ e/f/j/k │
└─────────┘
```

With `apply()`

```
df = df.with_columns([
    col('col1'),
    *[col('col1').apply(lambda s, i=i: s.split('/')[i]).alias(col_name)
      for i, col_name in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])]

    # or without 'for'
    # col('col1').apply(lambda s: s.split('/')[0]).alias('a'),
    # col('col1').apply(lambda s: s.split('/')[1]).alias('b'),
    # col('col1').apply(lambda s: s.split('/')[2]).alias('c'),
    # col('col1').apply(lambda s: s.split('/')[3]).alias('d')
])

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
shape: (2, 5)
┌─────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ col1    ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   │
│ ---     ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str     ┆ str ┆ str ┆ str ┆ str │
╞═════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ a/b/c/d ┆ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ e/f/j/k ┆ e   ┆ f   ┆ j   ┆ k   │
└─────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

It works, but probably there is more accurate way)

Comment: i dont have the same elements in the list in each row so the following throws an error

Answer (score 0):

With this way you do the string split to turn col1 into a list of strings. Then you loop over the lists and use `.arr.get` to extract each element into a separate column

```
(df
.with_column(pl.col("col1").str.split("/"))
.with_columns(
[pl.col("col1").arr.get(i).alias(str(i)) for i in range(len(df[0,"col1"].split('/')))
]
)
)
```

One challenge is whether you will have the same number of elements in the list in each row. In this solution I've assumed you have and have taken the length of the list in the first row to do the loop.

Comment: i dont have the same elements in the list in each row

Answer (score 0):

```
import polars as pl

#Create new column list(can be created dynamically as well)

new_cols=['new_col1','new_col2','new_col3',.....,new_coln]

#Define expression

expr = [pl.col('col1').str.split('/').arr.get(i).alias(col)
        for i,col in enumerate(new_cols)
        ] 
        
#Apply Expression

df.with_columns(expr)
```