# Polars join two dataframes if column value in other column

Tags: python-polars

I have two dataframes that I'd like to join if one column's value is contained in the other column.  The dataframes look like this:

```
df1 = pl.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3], "col2": ["x1, x2, x3", "x2, x3", "x3"]})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({"col3": [4, 5, 6], "col4": ["x1", "x2", "x3"]})
```

I tried to do:

```
model_data = df1.join(df2, on="col2")
```

Which does not produce the desired result.  What I'd like to see is something like this:

```
col1    col2            col3    col4
1       "x1, x2, x3"    4      "x1"
1       "x1, x2, x3"    5      "x2"
1       "x1, x2, x3"    6      "x3"
2       "x2, x3"        5      "x2"
2       "x2, x3"        6      "x3"
3       "x3"            6      "x3"
```

It's a question of how you do the join when one value is contained by another value.  I could not find good examples of this in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

You want to split your `col2` and `.explode()` similar to [python-polars split string column into many columns by delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73699500/python-polars-split-string-column-into-many-columns-by-delimiter)

Then you can perform the `.join()`

```
>>> (df1.with_column(df1["col2"].str.split(", ").alias("col4"))
...    .explode("col4")
...    .join(df2, on="col4")
...    .select(df1.columns + df2.columns))
shape: (6, 4)
┌──────┬────────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2       ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ str        ┆ i64  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪════════════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ x1, x2, x3 ┆ 4    ┆ x1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ x1, x2, x3 ┆ 5    ┆ x2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ x1, x2, x3 ┆ 6    ┆ x3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ x2, x3     ┆ 5    ┆ x2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ x2, x3     ┆ 6    ┆ x3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3    ┆ x3         ┆ 6    ┆ x3   │
└──────┴────────────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: To make it more robust, I'd probably do `df1.with_column(df1["col2"].str.replace_all(" ","").str.split(",")` in case there aren't always one space and one comma.  Maybe sometimes there's no space or 2 spaces, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach which *might be* counterintuitively faster is to do a cross join between them and then filter out the times that the `col4` is not in `col2`

That would look something like this...

```py
cj = df1.join(df2, how='cross')
filt = cj.apply(lambda x: x[3] in x[1])

(
    cj.with_column(filt.to_series().alias('filt'))
    .filter(pl.col('filt') == True)
    .select(pl.exclude('filt'))
)
```

Essentially what happens is that you create `cj` which is a df that has every row of df1 and df2 mashed together.  You then create `filt` which is just a series of Trues and Falses that you can filter by.  You filter by that and then do a select to exclude that helper column.  You just have to be careful of those index positions in the lambda expression of that second line.

You'll have to test the performance of this vs @jqurious's method.  If (big if, I don't know) this one is faster then it's because the `str.split.explode` isn't as efficient as just mashing everything together.  Unfortunately the `series.str.contains` method is looking for a fixed regex or literal so that's why this uses a lambda.